# wpa_gui fails to fetch wpa_supplicant status

Tags: gui, static-ip, wpa, web-interface

I am fairly new to Raspberry Pi. I wanted to make an Apache server with my Pi and I was trying to give it a static ip. But anytime I start up `wpa_gui` (or try to do anything with it for that matter), the program yells at me `Could not get status from wpa_supplicant`. My `/etc/network/interfaces` file looks like so:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.1.200
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

I do have a wirless adapter connected although `wpa_gui` does not see it. But we can obviously see that linux sees it because:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:c509 Logitech, Inc. Cordless Keyboard & Mouse
```

I  will note, however, `/var/run/wpa_supplicant/` doesn't exist. If any of you know how to fix this, I would love to hear.

Answer (score 1):

First, it you have error message like `Could not get status from wpa_supplicant` this obviously means that there's a problem with wpa_supplicant. Make sure you have it installed with`dpkg -s wpasupplicant`. If not, install it with `sudo aptitude install wpasupplicant`

If this fails to fix the problem, read on.

I suppose that you are trying to connect to a WPA/WPA2 WiFi using wpa_gui.

It seems that your WiFi adapter uses "exotic" chipset, called `rt2800usb`. It seems thar Raspbian doesn't fully support it. This chipset probably needs additional steps to enable which are described [here](https://wiki.debian.org/rt2800usb). After enabling the adapter you may define the WPA/WPA2 ESSID and pass in `/etc/network/interfces` as described [here](https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse#wpa_supplicant).